# UnsupportedEncodingException is not getting thrown, if we change final property value using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, encoding

```java
package com.java.random.practice;
    
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
    
public class App 
{
    private static final String ENCODING = "\\UTF-8";
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
        {      
            URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", ENCODING);
        }
}
```

Above code throws exception UnsupportedEncodingException when use "\" with encoding but when we use Reflection to modify the value then it does not show any exception, please see the below code:

```java
package com.java.random.practice;
    
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
    
public class App 
{
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
        {      
            App app=new App(); 
            Field field = app.getClass().getDeclaredField("ENCODING");
            field.setAccessible(true); 
            Field modifiersField =
            Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true); modifiersField.setInt(field,
            field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL); field.set(null, "\\UTF-8");
             
            String s= URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", ENCODING);
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Why this kind of strange behavior?

Comment: Please don't try to change `static final` fields. It doesn't work. It may or may not appear to work, but that may change at any point in any other release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values of *compilation time constants* are **inlined** by compiler.

What does it mean?
Lets say there is `private static final String STR = "Foo";`. Here we are sure (using standard language rules, without including reflection since it is a tool that breaks all guarantees language enforces, like: preventing accessing `private` members, modifying `final`, etc.) that value of `STR` should be always `"Foo"` and that information is also known at compilation time.

This allows compiler to optimize code like `System.out.println(STR);` and remove the need to lookup value of `STR` but instead use it directly which will produce same bytecode as if we would write `System.out.println("Foo");` (since value is known to compiler and "theoretically" always the same).

So even if we use reflection and reassign new value to `STR` it will not affect bytecode which represents `System.out.println("Foo");` **since it no longer depends on `STR`**.

In your case

```
String s= URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", ENCODING);
```

will be compiled as if you would write it as

```
String s= URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", "UTF-8");
```

(since `private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";` value of `ENCODINT` is `"UTF-8"` and that is inlined in places where `ENCODINT` is being used). So even if you assign new value to `ENCODINT` (here "\UTF-8") it can't affect bytecode which represents `URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", "UTF-8")` **since it doesn't use/refer to `ENCODING`**.

If you want to prevent inlining don't make `ENCODING` a *compilation* time constant. In other words ensure that assigned value will need to be "calculated" at runtime. For instance you can use `private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8".substring(0);`.

Comment: You have valid point, but here my question is why `URLEncoder.encode("anyValue", ENCODING)` is not throwing exception when i update the final `Encoding` value with "\\UTF-8" using reflection.

The same code throw exception when i simply put "\\UTF-8" in `Encoding`

Comment: @Abhishek I rephrased my answer a little. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: got your point, i have one following up question, if we just remove final and keep static for  `ENCODING` which means `ENCODING` is compile time but you will see in reflection we can change the value of it and it will throw exception :

`private static String ENCODING = "UTF-8";`

Comment: @Abhishek If we remove `final` modifier then `ENCODING ` will no longer be *constant*. So even if at compilation time compiler will know *current* value, it can no longer guarantee that this value will *always* be same (which `final` keyword guaranteed). So it no longer can use inlining since `ENCODING` value can change (now also you no longer need reflection to change it). So if you assign incorrect encoding like `"\\UTF-8"` exception is expected.